# VBA Macro crashes after 32000 rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA macro that copies rows from one worksheet into another based upon finding values in cells in 3 columns. The macro works, but crashes when it reaches row 32767. There are no formulas or special formatting in this row. Further, I have taken that row out, but it still crashes on that row number. Is this a limitation in Excel? There are some 43000 in the worksheet that is being processed.

Therefore, I ask what is wrong with my macro and how I can get it reach the end of the worksheet:

```
Dim LSearchRow As Integer
Dim LCopyToRow As Integer
Dim wks As Worksheet
On Error GoTo Err_Execute
   
 
For Each wks In Worksheets

    LSearchRow = 4
    LCopyToRow = 4
 
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Set wksCopyTo = ActiveSheet
    wks.Rows(3).EntireRow.Copy wksCopyTo.Rows(3)
   
    While Len(wks.Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0
        
        If wks.Range("AB" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "Yes" And wks.Range("AK" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "Yes" And wks.Range("BB" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "Y" Then
            
            Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
            Selection.Copy

   
            wksCopyTo.Select
            wksCopyTo.Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
            wksCopyTo.Paste

            'Move counter to next row
            LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1
            'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
            wks.Select
        End If
        LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1
    Wend
 
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A3").Select
    MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."
Next wks

Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "An error occurred."
```

Comment: IIRC VBA's `Integer` type is 16 bits wide.  Is there a `Long`?  I forget.

Comment: look up Integer in the help, then change it to Long

Comment: Thanks guys - yet all I needed to do was to change the datatype to a long

Comment: I also ran into this issue with MS Access 2000 while running a rather intense module.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The VBA 'Int' type is a signed 16-bit field so it can only hold values from -32768 to +32767. Change those variables to 'Long', which is a signed 32-bit field and can hold values from -2147483648 to +2147483647. Should be enough for Excel. ;)

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like an integer Problem

> The **Integer** and Long data types can both hold positive or negative
>   values. The difference between them is their size: Integer variables
>   can hold values between **-32,768 and 32,767**, while Long variables can
>   range from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

But which version are you using? Because:

> Traditionally, VBA
>   programmers have used integers to hold small numbers, because they
>   required less memory. In recent versions, however, **VBA converts all
>   integer values to type Long, even if they are declared as type
>   Integer.** Therefore, there is no longer a performance advantage to
>   using Integer variables; in fact, Long variables might be slightly
>   faster because VBA does not have to convert them.

This Information is directly from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164754(v=office.10).aspx)

**UPDATE**

Please also read the first comment! I was interpreting the MSDN Information the wrong way!

> Thats MSDN being misleading: VBA does not itself convert Integer to
>   Long. Under the covers the CPU converts integer to long , does the
>   arithmetic and then converts the resulting long back to integer. So
>   VBA integers still cannot hold numbers larger than 32K – [Charles
>   Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88173/charles-williams)

Comment: Thats MSDN being misleading: VBA does not itself convert Integer to Long. Under the covers the CPU converts integer to long , does the arithmetic and then converts the resulting long back to integer. So VBA integers still cannot hold numbers larger than 32K

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the Integer vs. Long issue by using a For Each rather than incrementing rows.  For Each is generally faster, as is avoiding Selecting Ranges.  Here's an example:

```
Sub CopySheets()

    Dim shSource As Worksheet
    Dim shDest As Worksheet
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim aSheets() As Worksheet
    Dim lShtCnt As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Const sDESTPREFIX As String = "dest_"

    On Error GoTo Err_Execute

    For Each shSource In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        lShtCnt = lShtCnt + 1
        ReDim Preserve aSheets(1 To lShtCnt)
        Set aSheets(lShtCnt) = shSource
    Next shSource

    For i = LBound(aSheets) To UBound(aSheets)
        Set shSource = aSheets(i)

        'Add a new sheet
        With ThisWorkbook
            Set shDest = .Worksheets.Add(, .Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count))
            shDest.Name = sDESTPREFIX & shSource.Name
        End With

        'copy header row
        shSource.Rows(3).Copy shDest.Rows(3)

        'loop through the cells in column a
        For Each rCell In shSource.Range("A4", shSource.Cells(shSource.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Cells
            If Not IsEmpty(rCell.Value) And _
                rCell.Offset(0, 27).Value = "Yes" And _
                rCell.Offset(0, 36).Value = "Yes" And _
                rCell.Offset(0, 53).Value = "Yes" Then

                'copy the row
                rCell.EntireRow.Copy shDest.Range(rCell.Address).EntireRow
            End If
        Next rCell
    Next i

    MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

Err_Exit:
    'do this stuff even if an error occurs
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "An error occurred."
    Resume Err_Exit

End Sub
```