# Copy Paste Loop Runtime Error 6

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following table:

```
Code     Year
8948KH   2003
         2004
         2005
         2006
923587   2003
         2004
         2005
         2006
938972   2003
         2004
         2005
         2006
```

Assume "Code" is in cell A1. I want the values of 8948KH, 923587 and 938972 to copy/paste themselves until they run into another code.

To do this I used the following code. which I found on Stackoverflow made by D Mason:

```
Sub replaceBlanks()

' define variables
Dim column As Integer
Dim row As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim previousValue As String
Dim value As String

' stop screen from updating to speed things up
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' use the active sheet
With ActiveSheet

    ' get the current cell selected and the last row in column selected
    column = ActiveCell.column
    row = ActiveCell.row
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, column).End(xlUp).row

    ' set previous value to the first cell
    previousValue = Cells(row, column).value

    ' iterate for every row between selected and last row with data in
    For i = row To lastRow
        ' set value = the content of that cell
        value = Cells(i, column).value
        ' if it contains nothing
        If Len(value) < 1 Then
            ' set the value of cell equal to the previous cell that had something in it
            Cells(i, column).value = previousValue
        ' if it contains something
        Else
            ' update the previous value and move on to next row
            previousValue = value
        End If

    Next i

End With

' update the screen at the end
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This works fine for very small loops. However, I need to loop approximately 6700 pieces of code spread out over 80.000 rows. Between each code and the next there are exactly 11 blank rows and I need them to stay there to copy the codes into.

If I try to do this, Excel yields a 'Runtime Error 6 Overflow' and refers to `lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, column).End(xlUp).row` in the debugger.

Is there any way to adjust the macro in order to keep Excel from generating that error?

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate question. Please see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10558650/42346

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this tidier alternative.

```
Sub Fill_in_the_Blanks()
    With Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Columns(1)
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Formula = "=A2"
        .Cells.Value = .Cells.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

This assumes (from your description and sample data) that A2 contains *8948KH* and that the cells are actually blank and not zero length strings returned by formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Select ColumnA, HOME > Editing, Find & Select, Go To Special…, check Blanks, OK, `=`, Up, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>