# For loop code (Compile errors)

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

I am doing a simple loop code where I want Y to equal 10 and each time it goes through the loop to +1 i.e. 10,11,12,13

However I am getting compile errors on the variables X and Y if anyone could let me know why this is occuring it would be much appreciated.

```
Dim targetrow As Long
targetrow = ActiveSheet.Range("Total").Offset(-2, 0).Row

Y = 10
For X = 19 To targetrow Step 1
If Range("K" & X) <> "" Then

Range("K" & X).Copy
Workbooks(PtchFile).Activate
Range("G" & Y).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False

Y = Y + 1
X = X + 1
Else
End If
Next X
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Do you not have to declare those variables? I mean `Dim Y As Integer` and `Dim X As Integer`?

Comment: If you are using `Option Explicit` which you should be, then you do need to declare them.  But @Racil Hilan asked the more important question.  What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare your variable as following above your code snippet:

```
Dim X as Integer
Dim Y as Integer
```

You may also want do activate the workbook where you copy your range before you copy the range, at the next iteration it will copy the Range("K" & X+1) from the Workbook PtchFile

cheers.

Comment: its worth noting that you may need to declare your variables as type `Long`. You declared `target` as `Long` which is great, especially if the row is greater than ~32,000 (see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558540/vba-macro-crashes-after-32000-rows). You will get an `Overflow` error if the X or Y is too high of a number for an `Integer` type.

Comment: I though it wasn't worth mentioning, but for anyone interested : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long , true there is no value in declaring variable as integer, but habits are hard to break =)