# Convert multiple csv files to tab delimited

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I need to save a selection of *.csv* files, under the same name, as *tab delimited* files.

I have the following code to select the files, specify the delimiter, and then iterate through the files, opening and saving them one by one.

The issue is the iteration.

```
Sub sandbox2()

    Dim xFilesToOpen As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xTempWb As Workbook
    Dim xDelimiter As String
    Dim xScreen As Boolean
    Dim strFileFullName As String

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    xScreen = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    xFilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.*), *.*", , , , True)
    xDelimiter = Application.InputBox("Delimiter: ", , ",")

    If TypeName(xFilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No files were selected", , "Sorry dude"
        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If

    For i = 1 To UBound(xFilesToOpen)
        Set xTempWb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(i))
        strFileFullName = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, ".csv", "")
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFileFullName + ".txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
        xTempWb.Close False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
        Set xTempWb = Nothing
    Next i

ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = xScreen
    Set xWb = Nothing
    Set xTempWb = Nothing
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, , "error"
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

This code will work for the first file, but then I get the error

> "Object variable or With block variable not set"

When looking at the folder, the first file is saved as a *.txt* file, but only the first.

Comment: What does the line `ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False` do within the loop when you already close the workbook earlier using `xTempWb.Close False`? Also I would replace `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` with `xTempWb.SaveAs`, because referencing active workbook is not reliable. If it doesn't help, please don't make us guess and state on which line the error appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better not rely on any *active* object (`Workbook`, in this case) and reference a proper object instance, instead

also, you should handle `Application.DisplayAlerts` by setting it to `False` *before* entering files loop and moving its setting back to `True` in the ExitHandler block and make sure you always set it should any error arise

so I'd go as follows:

```
Sub sandbox2()

    Dim xFilesToOpen As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim xScreen As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    xScreen = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    xFilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.*), *.*", , , , True)
    xDelimiter = Application.InputBox("Delimiter: ", , ",")

    If TypeName(xFilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No files were selected", , "Sorry dude"
    Else
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' set it to 'False' only once before entering the loop
        For i = 1 To UBound(xFilesToOpen)
            With Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(i)) ' open a workbook with current name and reference it
                .SaveAs Filename:=Replace(.FullName, ".csv", "") + ".txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False ' act on referenced workbook properties
                .Close False ' close referenced workbook
            End With
        Next i
    End If

ExitHandler:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True ' be sure to set it back to 'True' should any error take you out of your loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = xScreen
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, , "error"
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

please note I  got rid of

```
Dim xTempWb As Workbook ' no longer used

Dim xWb As Workbook ' never used
....
Set xWb = Nothing ' never set

Dim xDelimiter As String ' never used
....
xDelimiter = Application.InputBox("Delimiter: ", , ",") ' never used
```

and used `Dim i as Long`, as a general rule not to incur in any overflow error since an integers can reach up to some [32000 value or so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558540/vba-macro-crashes-after-32000-rows)